# Not being able to merge rows with MySQL 'UNION ALL'

Tags: sql, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to prepare a query for my SQL exam. The database is supposed to be a on demand radio database. This is my query, which is supposed to combine content/clip sessions with livestream sessions, merging them by radio name

```
SELECT
    COUNT(sessione.session_id) AS "Sessioni",
    COUNT(DISTINCT sessione.user_id) AS "Numero Utenti", 
    AVG(sessione.rating) AS "Rating Medio",
    SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(sessione.end_time, sessione.start_time)))) AS Tempo_Totale_Di_Ascolto,
    radio.radio_name
FROM sessione 
JOIN puntata ON puntata.palinsesto_id = sessione.palinsesto_id 
JOIN radio ON radio.radio_id = puntata.radio_id 
GROUP BY radio.radio_name 
UNION ALL
SELECT
    COUNT(sessione.session_id) AS "Sessioni", 
    COUNT(DISTINCT sessione.user_id) AS "Numero Utenti", 
    AVG(sessione.rating) AS "Rating Medio", 
    SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(sessione.end_time, sessione.start_time)))) AS Tempo_Totale_Di_Ascolto,
    radio.radio_name
FROM sessione 
JOIN radio ON sessione.livestream_id = radio.livestream_id 
WHERE sessione.livestream_id IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY radio.radio_name  
ORDER BY `radio_name` ASC;
```

This is the output I get:

[image]

The desired output should have the rows with the same radio names merged into one (which is what I thought I was doing with the UNION ALL operator), instead I get separate rows for BBC6 and Radio Capital. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it doesn't merge them. That's what `UNION` means: add the data from the additional query after the end of the first, so both sets of results are available. The only time you'll ever merge anything with a `UNION` is if you omit the `ALL` and the **entire row** (not just a key field) is duplicated between the queries.

If you want rows merged based on a specific field, you need to the wrap the UNION'd queries in an outer SELECT query, and do your grouping there. So instead of:

```
SELECT ..
FROM ..
GROUP BY ..

UNION <ALL>

SELECT ..
FROM ...
GROUP BY ..
```

You do this:

```
SELECT ..
FROM (
   SELECT ..
   FROM ..

   UNION <ALL>

   SELECT ..
   FROM ...
) t
GROUP BY ..
```

But even here for your case I suspect this will lead to erroneously double-counting some of the data. Instead, you may need to do a better job targeting which exact rows belong with each side of the `UNION`.

Comment: Re "after the end" no order is guaranteed

Comment: All right, thanks! I was under the wrong impression (from a colleague) that UNION added the data from additional queries whilst UNION ALL did the merging. I actually did as you said and worked perfectly. May I ask: what is the "t" before the GROUP BY for?

Comment: @sickboy83 The `t` is because the SQL language requires you to give a name (alias) to the expression in parentheses. It doesn't matter what the name is, but you have to provide one.

Comment: Thanks for putting up with me mate, much appreciated. It seems to be giving the expected output but I will double check to ensure that there's no double counting. Cheers.